# SURF and OpenSURF to color image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, surf

I am using SURF features in OpenCV where the input images are converted to GRAY image.

```
 cvtColor(object, object, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

When I went through the documentation of OpenSURF I realised that its not in grayscale.

My confusion is that can we apply SURF to any image formats (YUV, HSV, RGB) or we have to change and modify the program to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most feature detectors work on greyscale because they analyse the patterns of edges in the image patch. You can run SURF on any single colour channel from the colour formats you mention i.e. You can run it on Y, U or V from YUV images, or on H, S or V from HSV images. Not sure how OpenSURF treats this, but they must be using the greyscale image internally.

Comment: In addition: OpenSURF performs a grayscale convert as soon as it computes the integral image (needed by the detector). See `IplImage *Integral(IplImage *source)` which performs `IplImage *img = getGray(source);`.

Answer (score 0):

Like OpenCV if you given an image to OpenSURF that is not single channel, it calls `cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGR2GRAY)`. If you pass either a 3 channel image in a YUV, HSV, Lab etc, things will go horribly wrong because the image will have an inappropriate color conversion applied..

Comment: Therefore i if I am using YUV for example than i will have to just pass the Y channel in that case or will it be also wrong.

Comment: If you just pass in the Y channel (i.e. a single channel image), it will be fine (no color conversion will be applied). BTW, you can use cv::split() to turn the 3 channel YUV image into a vector containing 3 x single channel images.